# Why does Write-Host break EndInvoke() result collection from RunspacePool?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, runspace

If I invoke a simple script, such as 'childScript.ps1':

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $object
)

Write-Host $object
```

Using BeginInvoke, and ending with EndIvoke(), the write-host output is not available in the result.

E.g:

```
$childScript = get-content ".\childScript.ps1"
$myObject = "Example string"
$MaxThreads = 5
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $MaxThreads)
$RunspacePool.Open()
$asyncJob = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($childScript).AddParameter('object', $myObject)
$asyncJob.RunspacePool = $HostRunspacePool
$asyncJob.BeginInvoke()
$result = $asyncJob.EndInvoke($job.AsyncHandle) #will be empty
```

However, if i modify the childScript to be:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $object
)

Write-Output $object
```

The result would be "Example string".

If i mix write-host and write-output, the result would always be empty.
Is there good documentation on why this occurs?

How can i force only specific output to be captured in the result, even if we use write-xxx in addition to write-output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using `BeginInvoke()`, and ending with `EndInvoke()`, the `Write-Host` output is not available in the result.

That is correct, because [`EndInvoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.endinvoke?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#returns) only returns the actual output from your runspace:

> The output buffer created to hold the results of the asynchronous invoke, or null if the caller provided their own buffer.

---

Side note, by *"if the caller provided their own buffer"*, they mean if you're using one of the `*Invoke<TInput, TOutput>(...)` overloads, i.e.:

```bash
$mybuffer = [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[psobject]]::new()
$ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({ 'hello' })
$ps.EndInvoke($ps.BeginInvoke(
    [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[psobject]] $null,
    $mybuffer)) # No output from here

$mybuffer # Output is in this custom buffer
```

---

If you want the output generated by `Write-Host`, you need to check your instances [`Streams.Information`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatastreams.information?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-psdatastreams-information) property:

```bash
$ps = [powershell]::Create().
    AddScript({ Write-Host 'hello world' })
$ps.EndInvoke($ps.BeginInvoke())

$ps.Streams.Information # => `hello world`
```

Do note that `Write-Host` sends its output to the [**Information stream**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3#information-stream) as opposed to `Write-Output` which sends it to Standard output (stdout), referred as [**Success stream**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3#success-stream) by PowerShell.

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't aware that the overload existed for EndInvoke, so that was great to find out. I've modified my script to somewhat match the example you've given, and everything works as expected!

Comment: @user3012708 also, you can hook the same buffer to multiple runspaces ;) you dont need to create a new PSDataCollection for each runspace

Comment: Oh, that is cool, thanks for the tip!